# Correlation and P-value matrix for two matrices

Tags: heatmap, correlation, p-value

I am trying to produce a correlation heatmap comparing two data sets. Dataset 1 is gene expression (11x25 numeric) and dataset 2 is protein expression (11 x 33 numeric). I am able to produce a correlation heatmap of the different sized matrices using cor, but I run into issues using cor.test to calculate p-values for those correlations. I receive the error: Error in cor.test.default(qg_1,mpx_1): 'x' must be a numeric vector.

This is my code:

```
heat <- cor(qg_1,,mpx_1, use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')
corrplot(heat, method = "circle")
```

```
testRes = cor.test(qg_1, mpx_1)
```

I expected to receive the same matrix as cor() but with p values, but I received the error as stated above.